# Управляемый frame

Tags: php, iframe

Добрый день!
Помогите, пожалуйста решить задачу.
Требуется реализовать открытие страницы во фрейме на всю ширину окна с возможностью гулять по ссылкам, но при истечении определенного времени должна возвращаться исходная страница. Можно конечно сделать вот так:

```
<html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
        <meta name="author" content="" /> 
        <script src="/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="60" />

        <title></title>
    <style>
    html, body, div, iframe {margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;}
    iframe {display:block;width:100%;border:none;}
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>

      <div><iframe src=">"></iframe></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Но важно, чтобы при переходе по любой ссылке время начиналось сначала.

Можно ли вообще такое реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Можно почему нет.С помощью яваскрипта,при загрузке фрейма устанавливаете таймер,которые после окончания перезагрузит страницу. Функция `setTimeout()`

Comment: А счетчик будет обнуляться, если будет переход по ссылке внутри фрейма?